# gdb assertion failure

Tags: c++, gdb, assert

I am compiling a test case for some code I have written with g++ and trying to debug it with gdb on the command line. The code compiles without errors or warnings, but when I launch my executable with gdb I get the following error:

```
Assertion failed: (g.numPlayers>0 && g.numPlayers<=MAXPLAYERS && cin), function readScenario, file p3t3.cpp, line 141.
```

I am using the same exact input arguments with gdb as I am when I run the compiled program normally. Is there a reason something can compile without problems and yet throw an error within gdb?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass command-line arguments to your program, then you either need to use

```
$ gdb --args ./program arg1 arg2
```

or

```
$ gdb ./program
...
(gdb) run arg1 arg2
```

Comment: If I am reading arguments in from a file, would the format still be as you have described?

Comment: In what way are you doing that? edit: Do you mean you're redirecting standard input? If so, I believe you have to use the `run arg1 arg2 < inputfile` form.

Comment: I have an executable called p3t3. When I open it with gdb and give it arguments from the file "example.in," (for example, `(gdb) run example.in`) I get an assertion failure, even though the code compiles and runs correctly outside of gdb.

Comment: What command line do you use to run it when you aren't using gdb?

Comment: I use `./p3t3 <example.in> example.out`

Comment: OK. `gdb ./p3t3` with `run < example.in > example.out` should work then, I think.